trying to print 1 to n in 32bit arm
.text
.global main

main:
    adr r0,format
    ldr r1,=number
    bl scanf

    ldr r2,=number
    ldr r2,[r2]

    mov r3,#1

loop:
    mov r1,r3
    adr r0,format1
    bl printf
    add r3,r3,#1
    cmp r3,r2
    blt loop

    mov r0,#1
    bl exit


format: .asciz "%d"
format1: .asciz "%d\n"

.data
    number: .word 0

here are the compilation and execution commands:
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc print_first_n.S -o print_first_n
qemu-arm -L /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi ./print_first_n

when i execute the code and provide 5 as input
it is just printing 1
can somebody explain where is my mistake
i initially thought number variable wasnt referenced properly
but now everything looks good

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!  The problem is that calling functions like printf clobbers the so-called caller saved registers.  These are r0 to r3 as well as lr.  Try to save the data you want to keep across the function call in other registers or on the stack.

`.text
.global main
main:
adr r0,format
ldr r1,=number
bl scanf
ldr r3,=number
ldr r3,[r3]

mov r2,#1
adr r0,format1

loop:
mov r1,r2
bl printf
add r2,r2,#1
cmp r2,r3
blt loop
mov r0,#1
bl exit

format: .asciz "%d"
format1: .asciz "%d\n"
.data
number: .word 0`
i made r2 as my loop variable
and made r0,r3 not changing
but it is still same

It's r0 to r3 that are affected, so all of r0, r1, r2, r3.
